# Proxy.jsp Internal Server Error

Tags: geoserver, wms, popup, proxy, tomcat

I am using proxy.jsp file to get WMS GetFeatureInfo popup, I have dropped proxy.jsp file in /usr/lib/cgi-bin and added allowedHosts. I changed     OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.jsp?url=";
if I clicked on any feature it is displaying like

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.1.1 Port 80**  on the popup.

Error I am getting in error log.

> [Wed Jul 30 10:57:00 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/proxy.jsp' failed, referer: http://xxx.xxx.x.x/rjy/GISShops.html
>   [Wed Jul 30 10:57:00 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: proxy.jsp, referer: http://xxx.xxx.x.x/rjy/GISShops.html

Can anyone please help me how to cure this error?

Here is my proxy.jsp file

```
    <%@page session="false"%>
<%@page import="java.net.*,java.io.*" %>
<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%

/**
* This is a white list proxy that could be used the prevent an error due to
* JavaScript Same Origin Policy.
*
* CAUTION: It might break some sites and it's a security risk because
* people can use this proxy to browse the web and possibly do bad and/or illegal stuff
* with it.
* It can load any content type.
* This proxy implementation was inspired by the proxy.cgi script of OpenLayers
* {@link http://openlayers.org}
* To use this in OpenLayers you have to set OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "Url/To/This/Proxyfile/proxy.jsp?";
* within your JavaScript code <br>
* The base code of the proxy has been provided by SNIPPLR
* {@link http://snipplr.com/view/17987/jsp-proxy-for-javascript-applications/}
*
* @author terrestris GmbH & Co. KG
* @author Christian Mayer
* @author Marc Jansen
*
* @license BSD see license.txt
*
*/
String[] allowedHosts = {
"www.openlayers.org", "openlayers.org",
"labs.metacarta.com", "world.freemap.in",
"prototype.openmnnd.org", "geo.openplans.org",
"sigma.openplans.org", "demo.opengeo.org",
"www.openstreetmap.org", "sample.azavea.com", 
"vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org", "localhost", "localhost:8181", 
"localhost:80","192.168.1.1",
"192.168.1.1:8181","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8181"
};
HttpURLConnection con = null;
try {
String reqUrl = request.getQueryString();
String decodedUrl = "";
if (reqUrl != null) {
reqUrl = URLDecoder.decode(reqUrl, "UTF-8");
}
else {
response.setStatus(400);
out.println("ERROR 400: No target specified for proxy.");
}

// extract the host
String host = "";
host = reqUrl.split("\\/")[2];
boolean allowed = false;

// check if host (with port) is in white list
for (String surl : allowedHosts) {
if (host.equalsIgnoreCase(surl)) {
allowed = true;
break;
}
}

// do the proxy action (load requested ressource and transport it to client)
// if host is in white list
if(allowed) {
// replace the white spaces with plus in URL
reqUrl = reqUrl.replaceAll(" ", "+");

// call the requested ressource
URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());
String reqContenType = request.getContentType();
if(reqContenType != null) {
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", reqContenType);
}
else {
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
}

int clength = request.getContentLength();
if(clength > 0) {
con.setDoInput(true);
byte[] idata = new byte[clength];
request.getInputStream().read(idata, 0, clength);
con.getOutputStream().write(idata, 0, clength);
}

// respond to client
response.setContentType(con.getContentType());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String line;
int i = 0;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
out.println(line);
}
rd.close();
}
else {
// deny access via HTTP status code 502
response.setStatus(502);
out.println("ERROR 502: This proxy does not allow you to access that location.");
}

} catch(Exception e) {

// resond an internal server error with the stacktrace
// on exception
response.setStatus(500);
byte[] idata = new byte[5000];

if(con.getErrorStream() != null) {
con.getErrorStream().read(idata, 0, 5000);
}

out.println("ERROR 500: An internal server error occured. " + e.getMessage() + " " + new String(idata));
}
%>
```

Comment: This is probably a dead thread at this point, but note that cgi-bin and jsp are usually different things... Java server pages are typically run in a tomcat container; cgi-bin wants to just run the file as an application or script